# How can I make carousel use 2 row in 1 column using Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

From what I understand about row and col,
number 1 would be one row with .col-12,
then number 2 and 3 in one row but with carousel in the middle using two row. can it be done?

```
            <!--Carousel & Main Menu-->
        <div class="container websiteheader">
        <br>
        <!--New Menu-->
            <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                        <a href="bim.htm"><img class="center-block" src="images/menu/icon-new.png"></a>
                        <h4 class="text-center">New</h4>
                    </div>
             </div>
        <!--New Menu-->


            <div class="row">
                <!-- Support Menu-->
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <img class="center-block" src="images/menu/icon-support.png">
                    <h4 class="text-center">SUPPORT</h4>
             </div>
                <!-- Support Menu-->
                <!-- Carousel-->
                <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                    <!--Carousel Bullets Indicators-->
                    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                    <li data-target="myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                </ol>
                    <!--Carousel Bullets Indicators-->

                    <!--Carousel Item List-->
                    <div class="carousel-inner">
                        <div class="item active">
                            <img src="images/carousel/index/index-001.jpg" width="100%" alt="VNIX MY">
                            <div class="carousel-caption">
                              <h3>Title 1</h3>
                                <p>Para 1<br>
                                Para 2<br>
                                Para 3</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <img src="images/about/index-002.jpg" width="100%" alt="VNIX MY">
                            <div class="carousel-caption">
                              <h3>Title 2</h3>
                                <p>This is slider 2 paragraph</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <img src="images/about/index-003.jpg" width="100%" alt="VNIX MY">
                            <div class="carousel-caption">
                              <h3>Title 3</h3>
                                <p>This is slider 3 paragraph</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--Carousel Item List-->

                    <!-- Carousel nav -->  
                    <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="icon-prev"></span>
                 </a>  
                 <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="icon-next"></span>
                 </a>
                    <!-- Carousel nav -->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Carousel-->
                <!-- Services Menu-->
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <img class="center-block" src="images/menu/icon-services.png">
                    <h4 class="text-center">SERVICES</h4>
                </div>
                <!-- Services Menu-->
                <div class="col-md-10">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <img class="center-block" src="images/menu/icon-about_us.png">
                    <h4 class="text-center">ABOUT US</h4>
                </div>
                </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <img class="center-block" src="images/menu/icon-about_us.png">
                    <h4 class="text-center">ABOUT US</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        <br>
```

This is what I want to achieve http://s22.postimg.org/5h5n94s3l/image.jpg
This is currently I got from the codes http://s28.postimg.org/uf0kisou5/image.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this.. Give borders to them so that you can test it. This should work

```
<div class = "navbar">
</div>

<div class = "navbar">
   <div class = "row">
      <div class = "col-sm-3">
         <div class = "col-sm-12"></div>
         <div class = "col-sm-12"></div>
      </div>
      <div class = "col-sm-6"></div>
      <div class = "col-sm-3">
         <div class = "col-sm-12"></div>
         <div class = "col-sm-12"></div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>

<div class = "navbar">
</div>
```

Just add borders and custom height to see it in action. Be sure you did not customize the bootstrap css, just do it later if you see the result.

Comment: sorry for the missing '<' there but i am not recommending to add a row  div because `.row` has -margins and `.col` has paddings so omitting the `.row` there will result to the same output.

Comment: Interesting code by Nesmar.

I have adjusted a bit and found something else. a bit off what I want.

Here is what I got http://s16.postimg.org/dcrcjmdph/image.png
`<div class = "navbar">
</div>
<div class = "navbar">
   <div class = "row">
      <div class = "col-md-3">
         <div class = "col-md-12"><img class="center-block" src="images/menu/icon-1.png"></div>
         <div class = "col-md-12"><img class="center-block" src="images/menu/icon-2.png"></div>
      </div>`

Comment: `<div class = "col-md-7">
      <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
                  <div class="col-md-11">
              <!--Carousel Bullets Indicators-->
               .....
                 <!--Carousel Bullets Indicators-->
                
                 <!--Carousel Item List-->
                        ....
                     <!--Carousel Item List-->
                
                 <!-- Carousel nav -->  
    ....
                     <!-- Carousel nav -->
                   </div>
                    </div></div>`

Comment: `<div class = "col-md-1">
         <div class = "col-md-12"><img class="center-block" src="images/menu/icon-3.png"></div>
         <div class = "col-md-12"><img class="center-block" src="images/menu/icon-4.png"></div>
      </div>
      <div class = "col-md-2">
         <div class = "col-md-6"><img class="center-block" src="images/menu/icon-5.png"></div>      
         </div>
   </div>
</div>

<div class = "navbar">
</div>`

Comment: Is it possible to have something like this? http://s10.postimg.org/kfs3h26t5/image.png

Comment: Yes, all you need to do is add another `<div class="col-md-12">...</div>` inside the first `<div class = "col-md-3">`. You just have it setup as two `<div>`'s on the left and three on the right, just add another on the left. Doing `col-md-12` makes the element fill up the entire parents "row", placing the created element on bottom of the stacked `div` tags. In which increases the height of the entire row making room for the carousel.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply here. I did see all the images that had been attach. I think the its okay now. Any other concern

Comment: yes, thanks @SpencerWieczorek and Nesmar
I don't know why at first it doesn't work but your suggestion does the magic.

Comment: for more informartion, refer to bootstrap documentation, you will learn there. The only keep in mind if you are using grid systems in bootstrap 3 is that all `.col .container` has padding and `.row` has negative margin to overcome the paddings of `.cols` and `container`. Note also that it is a mobile first css framework.